# Override Firefox's Default Filename in the "Save Page As" Dialog

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to write a Firefox Add-on which removes some special characters from the default filename (highlighted in red in the image below) in the "Save Page As" dialog in Firefox. Does the Firefox SDK API offer some way to alter this filename?

[image: Save Page As dialog in Firefox]

Answer (score 1):

Check the defaultString of the [nsIFilePicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIFilePicker) e.g.

```
    var nsIFilePicker = Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker;
var fp = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/filepicker;1"]
        .createInstance(nsIFilePicker);
fp.init(window, "Select a File", nsIFilePicker.modeOpen);

    fp.defaultString = defaultString; //Process the string as you want

    fp.appendFilter(fileType, "*." + fileType);
    var rv = fp.show();
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. However, this creates a new instance of the "Save As" dialog. Is there any way to alter the filename of the File -> "Save Page As" dialog which is invoked by pressing Ctrl+S?

Comment: Well, I never did it but in that case you may need to retrieve the chrome window (getMostRecentBrowserWindow) and asking her the proper node (it could be this one: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/filepicker/content/filepicker.xul) then change the values of the XUL elements